# JavaScript-created dropdown list glitch in WebView under Android

Tags: javascript, android, drop-down-menu, webview

I'm testing my app with Galaxy Tab with Android 2.2 and found following issue inside WebView component. I have local HTML page, generated on fly. When I have SELECT within HTML like this:

```
<select class='dd'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2' selected=selected>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

it causes following **problems**:

1. You can see dropdown, but can't select it, until you change zoom in WebView.
2. Ever after you can select dropdown and select option, the initial option value persists in dropdown (although `onchange` fired):
   [image]

Comment: Did you solve this?Please write your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the second issue try:

```
sl.bind("ontouch", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I need for pure JavaScript, without jQ.